# Windows - Elixir 'mix' is undefined within iex intepreter

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I want to build an application using 'mix' command.

> mix new appname --module MODULE

But on the iex interpreter it isn't recognized

[image]

I read online another alternative to running what I want is to pass it as a script argument:

> $ bin/elixir bin/mix new appname --module MODULE

but this doesn't work either

Comment: By the way Windows has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mix` is an executable that you need to run from your OS shell, not the Erlang/Elixir shell.